# In a three phase choke, is the rated current per phase or for all 3 together?

Tags: current, inductor, phase

In a 3-phase choke, for example here: https://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/744839010400.pdf

What is the current rating?
For the inductance it says 3x10.5mH, so its 10.5mH in each phase and if I parallel these together it will be 1 third of that.

But for the current rating it just says 40A, is this also per phase or with all 3 paralleled together?

Comment: Are you planning on running it as a differential choke when you say parallel the three windings? That won’t work in that case as you would saturate the core.

Comment: I need an inductor that will take 60A-80A and be in the range of a few mH. It is for a halfbridge single phase inverter

Comment: As the (differential mode) output choke?

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I parallel these together it will be 1 third of that.

Actually, no. Since the windings are coupled magentically, it's as if you had a single winding with the same number of turns (same inductance) but 3× the current capacity.

The formula for parallel inductors only applies when they are not coupled.

If each winding can handle 40A, then the three in parallel can handle 120A, assuming the core doesn't saturate or anything.

Answer (score 1):

> But for the current rating it just says 40A, is this also per phase or
>   with all 3 paralleled together?

It has to be used in a 3 phase supply-load set up for this current to be relied upon. So, what happens in a 3 phase supply-load scenario that means you can reliably use it on loads of 40 amps?

For a reasonably balanced supply and a reasonably balanced load, the average current in the input terminals is zero and this means that the common core elements of the choke have zero net magnetic field and will not saturate: -

[image]

Given that the one you list is constructed like this: -

[image]

There will be very little magnetic flux in the core at normal AC operating frequencies and of course that means very low saturation of the core. If you used it in a single phase situation there are no cancellation of fluxes and I doubt that it would operate above a load current of more than a couple of amps.

It is a 3 phase device intended to be used on a 3 phase supply with a 3 phase load (all of which is reasonably balanced). If you can't understand why 3 phase load currents have an average value of zero then that is another question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand now.

Could you explain what would happen in a 'single phase' one like this https://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/7448263505.pdf ?

Even though it is 'single' it still has 2 paths. What would happen if I just used one of them and put 35A through it?

Comment: @AQUAMAN providing that the load current flows in both coils produce opposing ampere-turns then it won't be saturated either. That configuration is called a common-mode coil as opposed to the same coil used differentially. When used differentially it will saturate under much lower levels of load current because the ampere-turns are additive as opposed to subtractive.

Comment: @Andy Since he mentions parallel, I’m afraid air he was fooled by the high inductance value of some catalogue CM inductor and want to use it on the output of his half-bridge.